# Is it possible to set different fee for each account in bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have following accounts in bitcoin core:

```
ajit@AjitSoman:~/git$ bitcoin-cli listaccounts 
{
  "": -0.83002768,
  "1": 1.10000000,
  "1470": 0.56739259,
  "1521": 0.63600000,
}
ajit@AjitSoman:~/git$
```

Is it possible i can set different fee for account `1470` and `1521`. If it is not possible then is it possible to set fee in `sendFrom` command